# Shared Preferences Not Applying Changes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have an activity (A) that checks my server for APK updates. When this function is called, whether there is or is not an update, I need the shared preferences to be edited so the application knows to skip or run the actual update activity (B). Question 1 is, why are the shared preferences not being edited by activity (A)? Question 2 is, if they are being edited, why isn't activity (B) reading them?

Thank You in advance!

Shared preferences should be edited here (Activity (A)):

```
    private void parseJson(String result) {
    try {

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
        String updateMessage = obj.getString(Constants.APK_UPDATE_CONTENT);
        String apkUrl = obj.getString(Constants.APK_DOWNLOAD_URL);
        int apkCode = obj.getInt(Constants.APK_VERSION_CODE);

        int versionCode = AppUtils.getVersionCode(mContext);

        if (apkCode > versionCode) {
            if (mType == Constants.TYPE_NOTIFICATION) {
                showNotification(mContext, updateMessage, apkUrl);
            } else if (mType == Constants.TYPE_DIALOG) {
                SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("ActivityUpdatePREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
                ed.putBoolean("activity_update", true);
                ed.apply();
                showDialog(mContext, updateMessage, apkUrl);
            }
        } else if (mShowProgressDialog) {
            SharedPreferences pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("ActivityUpdatePREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_update", false);
            ed.apply();
            Toast.makeText(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.android_auto_update_toast_no_new_update), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "parse json error");
    }
}
```

Activity (B):

```
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityUpdatePREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("activity_update", false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        deleteCache(getApplicationContext());
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        functionUp();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps its a typo i see ActivityupdatePREF in activity a and ActivityPREF in activity b

Comment: @RobertI wow, can't believe I missed that. I fixed and am waiting for app to compile and run now to test. Thank you!

Comment: @RobertI Unfortunately, it did not fix the issue. I have updated the code above.

Comment: could you put the code when you call the activity b?

Comment: @diegoveloper I am wondering this too. Check for race conditions, Make sure you write the result before B tries to read.

Comment: probably ed.apply(); or ed.commit() is never called because the conditions are not met.

Comment: @diegoveloper I cannot put the code where I call activity B because the check for update function does not reside there. I need the shared preferences to be edited based on whether or not there is an update available. How do you mean the conditions are not met?

Comment: @RobertI How do you mean check for race conditions? How would I do this?

Comment: Are you sure et.apply or et.commit is called?

Comment: @Zuuchq 1. Put Log.i("ActivityA","pref saved"); before you call commit / apply in activity A.  2. Put Log.i("ActivityB","reading preferences"); right before you call pref.getBoolean. You will have your answer from the logs.

Comment: @diegoveloper I'm fairly certain that it is being called because when I run the app I get "No Updates Available" which is called after ed.commit();

Comment: In that block where you supposedly show the Toast "No Updates Available" you are setting "activity_update" to false, which kinda makes sense with the rest of the code. And it also makes sense that it wouldn't start activity B since it will fail the if condition there. As far as I can tell at least.

Comment: Then functionUp() is called, right? What is the code?

Comment: @RobertI Log.i returns: android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@fc669fd

Comment: @Zuuchq attatch logs to the original post

Comment: @diegoveloper yes, the code runs as it should functionUp(); is: UpdateChecker.checkForDialog(MainActivity.this);

Comment: So, what is the problem? If you get "no updates available" your activity_update is false then go to functionUp()

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening. Because, if the functionUp() is running, then your shared prefs are properly updated and read by the code you have posted.

Comment: Could you check my answer please ?@Zuuchq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use commit() and not apply()**

> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent
>   storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory
>   SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to
>   disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on
>   this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is
>   still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are
>   completed as well as the commit itself.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: So I should try changing it to commit()?

Comment: Yes try that, and let me know

Comment: Just ran it, no luck

Answer (score 0):

You code is ok,you should check you `ed.apply();` is executed is your code .

In `Activity(A)` , you should check the order in which the program is executed .

**1.Make sure that `parseJson` method is executed .**

**2.If you parse `json` error ,you should check `JSONException`.**

```
Log.e(Constants.TAG, "parse json error");
e.printStackTrace();
```

**3.If `apkCode > versionCode` is executed ,Is`mType == Constants.TYPE_DIALOG` executed ?**

**4.If `apkCode < versionCode` is executed ,Is `mShowProgressDialog` true in your code ?**

And you can add Log to check it .

```
ed.apply();
Log.e(Constants.TAG, "SharedPreferences is apply");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ed.commit() instead of ed.apply()