# kotlin - applying changes from sharedPreferences instantly

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

In my app i have a settings fragment which the user can set data like the amount of decimal places they want. Currently, using shared preferences the app successfully remembers the last entered data when reopening the app. However the change is only applied when the user reopens the app and not when first applied.

the following code is located in the MainActivity.kt:

```
val sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.applicationContext)

 val decimalPlaces = sp.getString("decimalPlaces", "")


        sharedViewModel.form  = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")

        when(decimalPlaces!!.toInt()){
            0 -> sharedViewModel.form  = DecimalFormat("#,###")
            1 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.#")
            2 -> sharedViewModel.form  = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
            3 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.###")
            4 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.####")
        }
```

upon researching solutions to have the changes apply while still in the app, i came across the following:

[Commit() and apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318756/16448331)
Along with other similar approaches, However i was unable to successfully implement these methods.

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to have the changes apply without exiting the app?

Comment: where you set string?

Comment: the string is set using a list preference located in a settingsFragment,, depending on which item is clicked in the list a corresponding value located in an array is returned

Comment: once they set the value from fragment , did you refresh Mainactivity get string?

Comment: i currently have the code located in a function called loadsettings(), i call on this function within MainActivity.kt, i am unsure how i would refresh MainActivity

Comment: create interface in the fragment , implements in the activity. when some things changes in fragment call the interface that will trigger main activity. There refresh the sharedpreference

Answer (score 0):

Changes are being applied instantly but it seems that you are only reading shared preferences when app is started. in order to change your based on the changed value of decimal place, you need to inform your Activity that decimal place value is changed and it should update the view accordingly.

One way to accomplish this is to use a `LiveData` object and post changed decimal place value to it, when you save to shared preferences.

In `SharedViewModel` declare a LiveData object

```
val decimalPlaces : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
```

When you save value to shared preferences, update this `LiveData` as

```
fun saveToSharedPreferences(newDecimalPlacesValue: String){
    // Your code that saves to shared preferences
    decimalPlaces.postValue(newDecimalPlacesValue)
}
```

Finally `observe` this `LiveData` in your Activity and update UI

```
override fun onCreate(){
    ...
    sharedViewModel.decimalPlaces.observe(this, Observe{
        if(!it.isNullOrEmpty()){
            when(it.toInt()){
            0 -> sharedViewModel.form  = DecimalFormat("#,###")
            1 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.#")
            2 -> sharedViewModel.form  = DecimalFormat("#,###.##")
            3 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.###")
            4 -> sharedViewModel.form = DecimalFormat("#,###.####")
        }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: when observing the liveData, where should i put this code? Also

Comment: Type mismatch: inferred type is DecimalFormat but MutableLiveData<String> was expected  appears within the when statement when setting the new value for sharedViewModel.form

Comment: You need to post decimal places value to `LiveData`, dont post `DecimalFormat`